# Can't serve webapp from Tomcat configured in eclipse

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications, web-deployment

I have spring application that I deploy on a tomcat server configured in eclipse along with a frontend app that is placed inside src/main/webapp folder. The context path is /asig. It's used for REST calls.

I've added the webapp folder to Deployment Assembly:

[image]

Here is my target folder after mvn clean install:

[image]

However, when I launch the server I cannot access my front end app. I receive 404 and I don't know why.
I tried everything: https://localhost:8443/, https://localhost:8443/index.html, https://localhost:8443/asig, https://localhost:8443/asig/index.html and nothing works.

I've searched everywhere and the only answers I could find was to just to put my front end app inside src/main/webapp and everything will work...

Comment: 8443 is the port number (generally used for https).  Try "http://localhost:8080/index.html" which uses the default port 8080 for spring boot.

Comment: It is my intention to use https.
I did try 8080 and still it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have your application.properties setup to use https?  Can you post your application.properties file?